# How to define a namespace in spring

Tags: java, jsp, el

I've been working local on tomcat server 7, now I uploaded my project to a server but it has tomcat 6. So the following doesn't work:

```
model.addAttribute("category",cat);

<div class="span4">
            <h2>
                Category:
                <c:out value="${category}" />
            </h2>
            <br />
            <c:forEach items="${categoryList}" var="item">
                <div class="alert alert-init">
                    <c:url value="/getInit/${item.getiID()}" var="url" />
                    <a href="${url}"><c:out value="${item.getTitle()}" /></a>
                </div>
            </c:forEach>
        </div>
```

It gives me following error code:

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/views/categoryinitiatives.jsp(34,5) The function iIDGetter must be used with a prefix when a default namespace is not specified

I've been searching all over the web to find a solution for this problem, but without success. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Spring. It doesn't even have anything to do with Spring MVC, which is a difference although many people seem to think Spring is just a web framework. This question is about JSP / EL only.

Comment: You are right, this is about JSP Thanks for pointing me on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanna access a property of a bean using EL, just write `item.title` instead of `item.getTitle()`. It will automatically call the getter and probably solve your problem.

Moreover, `item.getiID()` isn't a valid name. If you have a property `iID` in your bean, you have to name the getter `getIID()` to access it using EL. Have a look at the [lowerCamelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) syntax.